# Oracle SQL aggregate Geometries (Longitude, Latitude)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, geospatial

I have this table

[image]

I wanted to sort by POS `ASC` and also aggregate the two columns X, and Y (so that these POINTS become a LINESTRING, EPSG:25832) so that my ID becomes Unique.

I don't have much experience with ORACLE SDO GEOMETRIES but with PostGIS.
Is there an easy way to do it? Since I didn't find any solution which worked correctly.

The output should be:

[image]

Any help maybe..? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate the coordinates into a string and convert it to an `SDO_GEOMETRY` type:

```sql
SELECT id,
       SDO_GEOMETRY(
         'LINESTRING(' || LISTAGG(x || ' ' || y, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pos) || ')'
       ) AS line
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id;
```

However, the string is limited to 4000 characters so it may fail if you have lots of coordinates.

If you just want the string (without converting it to an `SDO_GEOMETRY`) then remove the call to the `SDO_GEOMETRY()` constructor and just use `LISTAGG` on its own.

---

Alternately, you can generate the `SDO_GEOMETRY` object directly using `UNPIVOT` and `CAST`/`COLLECT`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       SDO_GEOMETRY(
         2002,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1),
         CAST(COLLECT(value ORDER BY pos, coord) AS SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY)
       )
FROM   table_name t
UNPIVOT (value FOR coord IN (x AS 1, y AS 2))
GROUP BY id
```

If you want it as a WKT string then:

```sql
SELECT id,
       SDO_GEOMETRY(
         2002,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1),
         CAST(
           COLLECT(value ORDER BY pos, coord)
           AS SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY
         )
       ).get_WKT() AS wkt
FROM   table_name t
UNPIVOT (value FOR coord IN (x AS 1, y AS 2))
GROUP BY id
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | WKT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LINESTRING (362019.6 5693216.74, 361967.53 5693180.03) |
| 2 | LINESTRING (361993.564 5693198.385) |
| 3 | LINESTRING (361993.564 5693198.385) |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g5Z3lkZL)

---

In Oracle 11g, if you just want the WKT string then you can create the types and function:

```sql
CREATE TYPE coord IS OBJECT(x NUMBER, y NUMBER)
/

CREATE TYPE coord_table IS TABLE OF coord
/

CREATE FUNCTION coords_to_wkt(
  i_coords IN coord_table
) RETURN CLOB
IS
  v_clob CLOB;
BEGIN
  IF i_coords IS NULL OR i_coords.COUNT = 0 THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  v_clob := 'LINESTRING(' || i_coords(1).x || ' ' || i_coords(1).y;
  FOR i IN 2 .. i_coords.COUNT LOOP
    v_clob := v_clob || ',' || i_coords(i).x || ' ' || i_coords(i).y;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN v_clob || ')';
END;
/
```

and use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       coords_to_wkt( CAST( COLLECT( coord(x, y) ORDER BY pos ) AS coord_table ) ) AS wkt
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76931c/9)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It failed because its to long.. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: @ColabCoderDE Yes, it is already in the answer. Use `CAST`/`COLLECT`.

Comment: I tried it but got this error: ORA-22814 @MT0

Comment: @ColabCoderDE It works for me with your sample data in the fiddle. Please provide a [MRE] that replicates the error.

Comment: I have Oracle 11g. Is that important? @MT0

Comment: can you please give an answer to this? I tried it with 11g2 and it does not work. I get NULL Values. @MT0

Comment: @CodeoDE [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76931c/9) has two that work in Oracle 11g. You should also be able to use a recursive sub-query factoring clause but the fiddle doesn't seem to like it.